# React setState after Promise resolves in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am still new to React and trying to wrap my head around.

I am fetching some data from an API in `ProjectAPI.js` file.

```
const getProjects = async () => {
    const projectsAPI = Common.baseApiUrl + '/project';
    let projects = [];
    axios.get(projectsAPI)
    .then((response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i ++){
            let project = {
                projectNameInitials: "NO",
                projectNumber: response.data[i].projectNumber,
                projectName: response.data[i].projectName,
                clientName: response.data[i].client,
                currentStage: response.data[i].currentStage,
                lastUpdated: response.data[i].updatedOn
            }
            projects.push(project);
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return projects;
}
```

Then, in my React component I call this function and sets the state after the Promise resolves using `then`.

```
componentDidMount(){
    ProjectAPI.getProjects().then((response) => this.setState({projects: response}));
}
```

I try to retrieve the same from the `state` in my `render()` function.

```
render(){
    const {
        projects,
      } = this.state;
    //...
}
```

This does not work and I get `projects` as empty array inside `render()` function. However, using the React dev tools, I can see the state is having the exact data. Interestingly, when I modify one of the state value manually using React dev tools, the `render()` is able to retrieve the state data, since it triggers the `render()` again. Any idea what I am doing wronng here?

Comment: projects will return first before promise resolved. try async-await then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause `getProjects` return empty array. Try this

```
const getProjects = () => {
    const projectsAPI = Common.baseApiUrl + '/project';
    let projects = [];
    return axios.get(projectsAPI)
    .then((response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i ++){
            let project = {
                projectNameInitials: "NO",
                projectNumber: response.data[i].projectNumber,
                projectName: response.data[i].projectName,
                clientName: response.data[i].client,
                currentStage: response.data[i].currentStage,
                lastUpdated: response.data[i].updatedOn
            }
            projects.push(project);
        }
        return projects
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer if you explain a more about this so it can help others.

Comment: You can also setState Inside the `axios.get(projectsAPI)
    .then((response) =>{
this.setState({})
})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });`

Comment: Cause you return `projects` before asynchronous get request Common.baseApiUrl + '/project' done. So you get empty array instead of `data`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait for data to come, because in this case render method getting called before your data comes from api.

So Just put condition before you render if state is null then render null else your html

```
render(){
const {
    projects,
  } = this.state;
{projects && 'your code' }
```

}